# combine two column from different txt file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-files

I have two txt file, without header, in both of them there are two column. I combine these columns, but they have not header, How can I set name as header for them.

```
with open('three.txt', 'w') as file3:
    with open('reference.txt', 'r') as file1:
        with open('test.txt', 'r') as file2:
            for line1, line2 in zip(file1, file2):
                print(line1.strip(), line2.strip(), file=file3)
```

Comment: Could you provide an input and expected output?

Comment: nesting of with statements looks poor.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a header row to the resulting file by writing the names to the file before the loop.

```
with open('three.txt', 'w') as file3:
    file3.write("header_col1, header_col2\n")
    with open('reference.txt', 'r') as file1:
        with open('test.txt', 'r') as file2:
            for line1, line2 in zip(file1, file2):
                print(line1.strip(), line2.strip(), file=file3)
```

Comment: thank you but, when I done it, can I access to each column with its header? it is like that

x  y  x  y
2.5000000e+00   2.4513000e+04 2.6814722e+00   2.4512842e+04

Comment: Since functionality only occurs when all files are open, I would personally have all the opens separated by comma on the first line to prevent such deep nesting.

Answer (score 0):

I will just propose that the `nested with statements` can be avoided with this code which looks cleaner:

```py
with (
    open("file1.txt", "r") as file1, 
    open("file2.txt", "r") as file2,
    open("file3.txt", "w") as file3
    ):
    
    # column headers before loop
    file3.write("header_col1, header_col2\n")

    for line1, line2 in zip(file1, file2):
        print(line1.strip(), line2.strip(), file=file3)
```